# How to pass the RedirectUrl from Create action GET to POST

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying pass the `RedirectUrl` value, that is populated when an action is decorated with `[Authorize]`, from the `GET` action to the `POST` action.

When I use either `TempData` or `ViewBag`, the hidden `INPUT` element is not populated.

`/Credential/Create GET`:

```
public IActionResult Create(string returnUrl = null)
{
    // either option has the same effect
    //TempData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

    return View();
}
```

resulting HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" />
```

If I supply a ViewModel:

```
public IActionResult Create(string returnUrl = null)
{
    // either option has the same effect
    //TempData["returnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

    CredentialViewModel credential = new CredentialViewModel();
    return View(credential);

}
```

then the input contains the class name of the view model:

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="Foo.Models.ViewModels.CredentialViewModel" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

`/Credential/Create POST`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmailAddress,Password")] CredentialViewModel credential, string returnUrl = null)
{
    // null
    Console.WriteLine(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: Reference how its done with AccountController and `Login.cshtml` specifically how Login method call works that into your results.  Its worth noting that your `<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="foo.Models.ViewModels.CredentialViewModel" />` as its coded will always show that entire namespace for that viewmodel since you didn't actually tell it to get a property, `value="@Model.ReturnUrl"` (for example).

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" />` but rather than a hidden input, you should be adding it as a query string value in the `<form>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@Context.Request.Query["returnUrl"].SingleOrDefault()" />
```

Then, you don't need to even bother setting `ViewBag`.